# find the value of data based on index or column

Tags: laravel, indexing, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I have a table with decimal data type whose column consists of z|one|two|three|four|five values.

the z-value column and columns one to nine are inputted from the user, for example I input -3.8 and columns one to nine I fill with 0.0001 then I submit it then the data is automatically saved and displayed in this picture
[image]

then I want to find the column value of the z value, for example I want to find the third column of the z value -3.8, by adding the indexm or column value that you want to find, so for example I want to find column 'three' then I write it in the search column like this -3.83, by adding one more number behind the comma.
[image]

and the result after searching
[image]

how to do it?

This is an example of a website that I want to create, you can try it yourself to better understand what I mean
https://setemen.id/project_statistik/tabel

my controller like this

```
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $chi = DataChi::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->get();
        $searchedColumn = null;

        if ($request->has('search')) {
            $input = $request->input('search');

            // Cari data berdasarkan nilai index dari digit kedua nilai Z yang dicari
            $chi = DataChi::where('nilai_z', 'like', '%.' . substr($input, -1) . '%')->get();
            $searchedColumn = $this->getColumnName(substr($input, -1));
        }

        return view('chi.index', compact('chi', 'searchedColumn'));
    }

    private function getColumnName($digit)
    {
        // $digit = substr($input, -1);
        $columns = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];
        return $columns[$digit];
    }
```

my view like this

```
   <!-- Kolom Pencarian -->

<div class="col-md-12 mt-3">
    <form action="{{ route('chi.index') }}" method="GET">
        <label for="search" class="form-label">SearchData:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search data">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<!-- Kolom Hasil Pencarian -->
<div class="col-md-12 mt-3">
    @if(isset($chi) && count($chi) > 0)
    <h3>Result Search:</h3>
    @if(isset($searchedColumn))
    <table class="table">
        <!-- Tabel Header -->
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nilai Z</th>
                <th>{{ $searchedColumn }}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <!-- Tabel Body -->
        <tbody>
            @foreach($chi as $data)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $data->nilai_z }}</td>
                <td>{{ $data->$searchedColumn }}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    @else
    <p>Data not found</p>
    @endif
    @endif
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure the `like` expression matches what is claimed? ... perhaps the `'like', '%.'` should instead be: `'like', '%.%'` ?

Comment: Did you debug you query using `$sql = $chi->toSql();` and try the query directly on db?

Comment: Also is this the correct way to extract `substr($input, -1)` as per your question? Can you a be a litte more clear as to what is the input and what is the expected output?

Comment: @PaulT. I tried but it didn't work before when I used %. it worked, but the result was not what I expected, I wanted to be able to take values one - nine from the inputted z values

Comment: @Adi Can you explain in more detail sir? I'm a bit confused about what you mean by debug query

Comment: @Adi I'm also not sure actually, so the values inputted to the table are z-value, zero, one, two to nine. for example I input z-value is 4.5 for values one - nine I fill in 50, 100, 200 to 1000, after inputting to the table, I want to find z-value data along with values one - nine but I input the number in the second digit after the comma, for example I want to find z-value 4.2 and take the fifth value, then I input 4.25, well this 5 will display the data sought which is 500 and so on with other data.

Comment: how is this `4.25,` matching the statement `second digit after the comma`? Which is why i asked what is the input and what is the expected output, and also show in basic array of what data is being stored in db for the given input, edit you question and add a section `Edit:` and post it there

Comment: @Adi I've edited my question, but I don't know how to add the Edit section:: but you can read the question that I edited.